# How to reserve a static IP for Azure Virtual Machines?

Tags: powershell, azure

Amazon have Elastic IP that you can assign to an instance,

How can I do that with Azure for existing VM?

(I don't want to change all my DNS entries if the IP changes)

I found some articles about running power shell commands 
1. http://michaelwasham.com/windows-azure-powershell-reference-guide/using-reserved-ip-addresses-with-microsoft-azure-virtual-machines/
2. http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/05/14/reserved-ip-addresses/
3. http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/04/22/static-internal-ip-address-for-virtual-machines/

But the commands are not recognized on my server (Windows server 2012 R2)

Any idea how can I do that?

This is the error that I'm getting on Power Shell:

```
PS C:\> New-AzureReservedIP – ReservedIPName "137.117.11.18" –Label "people-dns-ip" –Location "US West"
New-AzureReservedIP : The term 'New-AzureReservedIP' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureReservedIP – ReservedIPName "137.117.11.18" –Label "people-dns-ip" –Loc ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (New-AzureReservedIP:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you are missing the requiered CMD for PowerShell. Please download the Microsoft Webinstaller:

[Download Microsoft Web-Installer](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=320376)

and do an fresh installation of Microsoft PowerShell. After this you should be able to use the "New-AzureReservedIP" command. Maybe you are running an old version of PowerShell without this CMDlet.

[image]

For more information about installation PowerShell, see: [Configure and Install PowerShell (Azure)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/powershell-install-configure.md)

Comment: Thank you, now I'm getting a new error - New-AzureReservedIP : No default subscription has been designated. Use Select-AzureSubscription -Default <subscriptionName> to set the default subscription. I cannot find the correct subscriptionName (it says "BizSpark" on my Azure portal...)

Comment: use Get-AzureSubscription to see the list with correct names.